# Insert /Update Multiple spaces in a column in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I have a column of `varchar2` type of length 10 and I want to update that column with 7 spaces only but when I tried to select or update the value I get only one space.

How I can update the column as the 7 spaces is the only updatable value?

I tried following query:

```
create table temp(name varchar(10));
insert into temp values('       ');
update temp set name='      ';
commit;
select * from temp;
```

I get column with 1 space only;

I am using Oracle SQL*Plus.

Comment: I don't know about Oracle, but many databases do not store trailing spaces.

Comment: if you `select length(name) from temp;` does it return something unexpected? I suspect you are saying there is only 1 character because of some sqlplus presentation issue.

Comment: Oracle does store the spaces, if you specify them. Hatim - I just tried this here (Oracle 11gR2) and it preserved the spaces. And I'm using SQLPlus. Try `SELECT LENGTH(name) FROM temp` and see if it's just a display thing with SQLPlus.

Comment: @CleverIdeaWidgetry Might be  there is some presentation issue due to which only one space is showing while selecting table in SQL*PLUS.Is there anyway by which I can show the trailing spaces also.

Comment: @HatimKumar It depends on what you mean by "show". There are a variety of SQL*Plus presentation-specific settings to control these sorts of presentation issues. Perhaps elaborate on the actual SQL*Plus commands, beyond just your select statement.

Comment: @HatimKumar I also recommend you run, don't walk, to otn.oracle.com and download SQL Developer. There's no reason for interactive SQL*Plus any more.

Answer (score 3):

Don't worry, the 7 spaces are there. It's SQL*Plus that hides leading spaces on display. You can prove it by surrounding the name column with some extra symbols:

```
select '>'||name||'<' from temp;
>    <
```

EDIT: The culprit is the `WORD_WRAPPED`-feature. To stop SQL*Plus from eating the spaces, switch the format from `WORD_WRAPPED` to `WRAPPED` or `TRUNCATED`:

```
update temp set name = '   x   ';
SQL> column name format a10 word 
SQL> select name from temp;
NAME
----------
x

SQL> column name format a10 trunc
SQL> select name from temp;

NAME
----------
    x
```

Comment: Can I show  these spaces  anyhow without surrounded characters .

Comment: Thanks its really very helpful.Can we implement same thing in plsql dbms_output.put_line('     '); 
for displaying all the spaces in output.